# Помогите с передачей изображения по почте

Tags: forms, php, form

Здравствуйте, у меня есть форма, где передаётся текст и картинка и скрипт обработки, проблема в $message, не пойму чему он должен быть равен `$_FILES['image']['name']` или `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']`, если первое - то приходит картинка 1.jpg(по названию с компа), но сама по себе это просто пустой текст с форматом jpg, если второе - то вообще ничего не приходит, даже текст.
Вот сам скрипт, помогите разобраться, как я понял там нужно tmp и имя так распределить, чтобы и имя и код картинки передавались правильно.
Скрипт обработки:

```
$bound = "1234";
$name=$_POST['name'];
$link=$_POST['link'];
$message=$_POST['message'];
$image=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$address="Kirillka300000@yandex.ru";
$tema="TheSimsTowns - Загрузка файла";
$header.="MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$header.="Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=$bound\n";
$mes= "--$bound\n";
$mes.="Content-type: text/html; charset=\"windows-1251\"\n";
$mes.="Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\n\n";
$mes.="Имя файла: $name <br> Прямая ссылка на файл: $link <br> Ссылка на картинку: $image <br> Описание: $message";
$file = file_get_contents($image);
$mes.="\n\n--$bound\n";
$mes.="Content-Type: application/octet-stream; ";
$mes.="name=" . basename($image) . "\n";
$mes.="Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\n";
$mes.="Content-Disposition:attachment\n\n";
$mes.=base64_encode($file) . "\n";
$mes.="$bound--\n\n";
$go=mail($address, $tema, $mes, $header);
```

Answer (score 1):

Файл нужно загрузить на сервер, и только потом делать `file_get_contents`(). Например, вы загружаете example.jpg в папку files в корне вебсервера, и тогда

```
$img_path=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/files/example.jpg";
file_get_contents($img_path);
```